# TouchableOpacity OnPress is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to call a function which is passed using props when onPress is clicked. Below is my custom component.

**DrawerItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';

const DrawerItem = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.drawerItemContainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>
      <FastImage source={props.icon} style={styles.icon}  />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>
      <Text style={styles.drawerItemText} >{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);

export default DrawerItem;
```

Below is my custom component where I am using DrawerItem Component:

**SideMenu.js:**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {NavigationActions, SafeAreaView} from 'react-navigation';
import {ScrollView, Text, View, StyleSheet,ImageBackground, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
import DrawerItem from './DrawerItem';


class SideMenu extends Component {

  //This is the function which is not being called
  navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
    console.log('inside navigate screen');
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../../resources/images/drawer_background.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
        <View style={styles.drawer}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <FastImage style={styles.profilePicture} source={{uri: 'https://assets.entrepreneur.com/content/3x2/1300/20150406145944-dos-donts-taking-perfect-linkedin-profile-picture-selfie-mobile-camera-2.jpeg'}}/>
                <View style={styles.headerDetails}>
                    <Text style={styles.displayName}>Jen William</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.email}>jen@williams.com</Text>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.drawerBody}>
               //Below is how I am pasing navigateToScreen function 
              <DrawerItem onPress={() => this.navigateToScreen('Profile')}  icon={require('../../resources/images/myprofile_icon.png')} title='My Profile'/>
              <DrawerItem  icon={require('../../resources/images/cardrequest_icon.png')} title='Card Requests'/>
              <DrawerItem  icon={require('../../resources/images/search_icon.png')} title='Search'/>
              <DrawerItem  icon={require('../../resources/images/add_icon.png')} title='My Cards'/>
              <DrawerItem  icon={require('../../resources/images/signout_icon.png')} title='Sign Out'/>
            </View>
        </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

SideMenu.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object
};

export default SideMenu;
```

> Note: The props are being passed for sure as other values being passed
>   are accessible

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why you have two arrow functions (`navigateToScreen = (route) => () =>`)? Remove one as `navigateToScreen = (route) =>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a binding issue.

Instead of

```
 onPress={() => this.navigateToScreen('Profile')}
```

Try:

```
onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Profile')}
```

Comment: I disagree, @Jois need to remove extra arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Check your function :

```
navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
  console.log('inside navigate screen');
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: route
  });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}
```

It should be like this :

```
navigateToScreen = (route) => {
 console.log('inside navigate screen');
  const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: route
 });
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}
```

**There should not be extra brackets**

Answer (score 0):

Well! This may be funny. But believe me. I've experienced the same error and my code is simply as below,

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => console.log('Hi')}>
  <Text> Click Me! </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

After 15 minutes of time, I just existed from my console to restart my app. On pressing my npm console just thrown all of console logs.

Yah, sometimes npm console on my windows machine goes crazy to make me believe problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are running your code, this might not work. use **onClick**
Try this instead

```
<TouchableOpacity onClick={...}>
...
</TouchableOpacity>
```